# how to pass bean values to jasper report

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

In my xhtml file i have to pass employeeId and employeeName value from p:dialog to jasper report.I already created a jrxml(file), fields are $F{employeeId} and $F{employementName}.When i select command button it has to pass employeeId and employeeName to jasper report and generate as .pdf.But i don't know how to pass employeeId and employeeName in JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

```
      <p:dialog header="Employee Details" widgetVar="actDialog" appendToBody="false"
                resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

                <h:panelGrid id="dialog" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

                    <h:outputText value="Employee Id:" />
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{employeeBean.current.employeeId}"
                        style="font-weight:bold" />

                    <h:outputText value="Employee Name:" />
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{employeeBean.current.employeeName}"
                        style="font-weight:bold" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Report" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-check" style="width:70px;" action="#{employeeBean.generateReport}"/>
          </p:dialog>
```

Bean:

```
    private List<EmployementScheduleDTO> userList;
    private EmployementScheduleDTO current;

    public List<EmployementScheduleDTO> getUserList() {
    return userList;
   }

    public void setUserList(List<EmployementScheduleDTO> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
   }

    public EmployementScheduleDTO getCurrent() {
    return current;
   }

    public void setCurrent(EmployementScheduleDTO current) {
    if (current != null) {
        this.current = current;
    }
    }

    public void generateReport()
   {
    reportGeneration(current, userList);
   }


    public void reportGeneration(EmployementScheduleDTO employeedto,List<EmployementScheduleDTO> a_beanList)
   {
     try
        {
            URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/reports/employee.jrxml");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(url.getPath());
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrDataSource =
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(a_beanList);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jrDataSource);

        }
        catch (JRException jre)
        {
          jre.printStackTrace();
        }
     catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }
```

Comment: Assuming that `current` is holding a reference to a member of `userList`, I don't see why this isn't working. Could you provide examples of actual and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found answer pass value from bean to jasper report.Thank you for those who are respond me...

```
public EmployeeBean report(String empid,String empname)
{
    EmployeeBean empbean=new EmployeeBean();
    empbean.setEmployeeId(empid);
    empbean.setEmployeeName(empname);
    return empbean;
}

public void init() throws JRException
{

    String employeeid=current.getEmployeeId();
    String employeename=current.getEmployeeName();
    ArrayList<EmployeeBean> databeanlist=new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
    databeanlist.add(report(employeeid, employeename));
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beancollection=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(databeanlist);
    String realpath=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("common/reports/jasperreport.jasper");
    jasperprint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(realpath, new HashMap(),beancollection);
}

public void generateReport() throws JRException, IOException
{
    logger.info("enter into generate report");
    init();
    HttpServletResponse httpservlet=(HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpservlet.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=schedule.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream servletout=httpservlet.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperprint, servletout);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```